# Why Dronacharya demanded to make King Drupada prisoner in his Guru Dakshina?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya

Why Dronacharya demanded to make king Drupada prisoner in his gurudakshina? any specific reason?

Gurudakshina was for Duryodhana(Kaurava and Pandavas), then why did he take Karna and army to take King Drupada?

Comment: @ram I have seen this in BR Chopra Mahabharata

Comment: Did you watch the full series ? does it show where drupada refused to acknowledge the school-days friendship between him & drona when drona came to meet him after many years for some help to alleviate his poverty ?

Comment: yes @ram I do not have to answer here, I am asking questions here

Comment: Yes @ram , I understand what you are saying, if you know answer, please provide an answer here

Comment: https://youtu.be/3D2rmMdH9U4?list=PLtaXzx-VKKfF-BCfR4xhJHu4YmuPVKkMf&t=383

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89000/discussion-between-udhav-sarvaiya-and-ram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions are:

> - Why Dronacharya demanded to make king Drupada prisoner in his gurudakshina? any specific reason?
> - Gurudakshina was for Duryodhana(Kaurava and Pandavas), then why did he take Karna and army to take King Drupada?

---

[Drupada, the son of Prishata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01132.htm), used every day to come to the hermitage of Bharadwaja to play with Drona and study in his company. When Prishata was dead,  Drupada  became the king of the northern Panchalas.

After the death of his father Bharadwaja, Drona approached Parasurama and obtained all knowledge about Divine asthras.  Thereafter, he went to see his friend Drupada, who was now the King of Panchala.

However, Drupada, intoxicated with the pride of wealth, [ridiculed Drona](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01133.htm).

After imparting knowledge of weapons to Pandavas and Kauravas, [Drona asked](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01141.htm) of them the fee, saying,

> 'Seize Drupada, the king of Panchala in battle and bring him unto me.
>   That shall be the most acceptable fee.'

---

Karna was also a [disciple of Drona](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01135.htm).  Hence, he joined Duryodhana in capturing Drupada.

> Then Drona endued with great prowess taught the sons of Pandu (the use
>   of) many weapons both celestial and human. And, O bull of the Bharata
>   race, many other princes also flocked to that best of Brahmanas for
>   instruction in arms. The Vrishnis and the Andhakas, and princes from
>   various lands, and the (adopted) son of Radha of the Suta caste,
>   (Karna), all became pupils of Drona.